# Is there a disaster recovery strategy plan if someone deletes whole azure devops organization?

Tags: azure-devops, disaster-recovery

What is disaster recovery options provided by Microsoft if we delete some resources from azure DevOps like Build/release pipeline , Repos or even the whole organization.?

Please specify some best practices?

Comment: Contact Microsoft?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supports soft-delete on things like repositories and even the entire organization.

- Repositories, when deleted, go into a "Recycle Bin" from which you can recover recently deleted items (through the REST API, linked below)
- Organizations can be restored by contacting Microsoft
- Pipelines, if you're using YAML pipelines, are in Git or Github, and so are managed and replicated (as that's how Git operates - every replica is a backup)

With that said, these are not "Disaster Recovery" options - DR applies to outages and overall availability when something happens on Microsoft's end. What you're talking about is protecting your resources from mistakes committed by someone on your side of the equation.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/restore%20repository%20from%20recycle%20bin?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0